# Scale up inner divs height , width according to outer div and decrease the no. of inner divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three equally divided vertical divs having many divs inside each of the vertical divs as follows.

[image: When browser is not resized]

I want the inner divs to wrap to a 2 column or 1 column grid (depending on browser height width) with each divs height width increasing on browser resize. Presently the divs wrap around but still some extra space is left and I want the inner divs to increase in size with browser size decreasing filling that extra space.

Here is the image when i resize the browser

[image: after i resize the browser]

My HTML is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.main {
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.verticalReports {
    width: 32%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.verticalTiles {
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #e0d8ed;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    float: left;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="verticalReports">
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="verticalReports">

            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="verticalReports">
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
            <div class="verticalTiles"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some media queries at the breakpoints.

```
@media (max-width: 940px) {
    .verticalTiles {
        width: 45%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/wh7kD/

Might want to look into some responsive grids like http://responsive.gs/ or http://www.gumbyframework.com/docs/grid

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. But then I have to use this on really big screen and very small screens as well and i am not sure what will be the screen sizes. So i cannot keep on changing tile sizes depending on screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need javascript for this. what happens in your example is that you have three 30% wide elements with 10 px margin left, when you resize the browser, the 30px from the three tiles added up is less than the 10% remaining from the width of the tiles and they don't fit anymore, try using relative values for the margin like margin-left: 3%

ok, so based on your comment, you should use something like this:

```
    function wiwi() {
    var tenpercent = $('.verticalReports').width() / 10;
    if ( tenpercent < 30 ) {
        $('.verticalTiles').css('width','45%');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    wiwi();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        wiwi();
    });
});
```

Comment: If i change the margins to relative values the div's dont wrap around anymore.

Comment: oh yes, I misunderstood your question I think, basically you want to keep them always as wide as the box, you would have to measure how much is 1% in the initial screen width, and on window resize check if 10% is less than 30 pixels, if it is, change the width of verticalTiles to something like 45% each. Make a javascript function and call it with jquery's `$(window).resize();`

Comment: Thanks. This is also working fine. But once i resize ,the div takes a 2 column grid and when i get back to my normal browser size the div has still 2 column grid, which earlier had 3 column grid .And this doesnt help me if a reduce the browser size very small, like ipad's size, the tiles come in one column with extra space not filled up. Can i use ems in some way to handle this.

Comment: you have to adjust it for the reverse, add something like this `if (tenpercent > 30 ) { $('.verticalTiles').css('width','30%'); }` to the function, also you have to add something for when only one column appears and make them 90% wide..